# Add a column from another dataframe if the substring of its indices match the indices of the other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

`dfs_GSE159115` is a dictionary of AnnData objects, which is used for handling annotated data matrices in memory and on disk, positioned between pandas and xarray.
The `anno_GSE159115` is annotation.

I want to add the column `anno` from `anno_GSE159115` to the AnnData objects in `dfs_GSE159115` if the substring after the last `_` delimiter of `anno_GSE159115.index` matches the `dfs_GSE159115[sample_id].obs.index`.

Code:

```
# Iterate through each sample and assign annotations
for sample_id, adata in dfs_GSE159115.items():
    obs_index = set(adata.obs.index)
    anno_index = set(anno_GSE159115.index.str.rsplit('_', n=1).str.get(1))
    
    # Filter dfs_GSE159115 to retain only the rows with matching indexes
    anno_GSE159115.index = obs_index.intersection(anno_index)
    matching_annotations = anno_GSE159115.loc[anno_GSE159115.index, "anno"]
    
    # Create or assign the "anno" column in the observation metadata
    adata.obs["anno"] = matching_annotations.values
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [149], in <cell line: 2>()
      4 anno_index = set(anno_GSE159115.index.str.rsplit('_', n=1).str.get(1))
      6 # Filter dfs_GSE159115 to retain only the rows with matching indexes
----> 7 anno_GSE159115.index = obs_index.intersection(anno_index)
      8 matching_annotations = anno_GSE159115.loc[anno_GSE159115.index, "anno"]
     10 # Create or assign the "anno" column in the observation metadata

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5588, in NDFrame.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   5586 try:
   5587     object.__getattribute__(self, name)
-> 5588     return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   5589 except AttributeError:
   5590     pass

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/properties.pyx:70, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__()

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:769, in NDFrame._set_axis(self, axis, labels)
    767 def _set_axis(self, axis: int, labels: Index) -> None:
    768     labels = ensure_index(labels)
--> 769     self._mgr.set_axis(axis, labels)
    770     self._clear_item_cache()

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py:214, in BaseBlockManager.set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
    212 def set_axis(self, axis: int, new_labels: Index) -> None:
    213     # Caller is responsible for ensuring we have an Index object.
--> 214     self._validate_set_axis(axis, new_labels)
    215     self.axes[axis] = new_labels

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/base.py:69, in DataManager._validate_set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
     66     pass
     68 elif new_len != old_len:
---> 69     raise ValueError(
     70         f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "
     71         f"values have {new_len} elements"
     72     )

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1167 elements, new values have 107 elements
```

Input:
`dfs_GSE159115.items()`

```
dict_items([('GSM4819737', AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 6453 × 33694
    var: 'gene_ids'), ('GSM4819735', AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 1896 × 33694
    var: 'gene_ids'), ('GSM4819728', AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 923 × 33694
    var: 'gene_ids'), ('GSM4819725', AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 1704 × 33694
    var: 'gene_ids'), ('GSM4819733', AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 1644 × 33694
    var: 'gene_ids'), ('GSM4819738', AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 3635 × 33694
    var: 'gene_ids'), ('GSM4819726', AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 1410 × 33694
    var: 'gene_ids')])
```

`dfs_GSE159115["GSM4819737"].obs` (no columns; row name only)

```
AAACCTGAGACGACGT-1
AAACCTGCACGGCTAC-1
AAACCTGCAGTATCTG-1
AAACCTGCAGTCAGCC-1
AAACCTGGTAAATGTG-1
```

`dfs_GSE159115["GSM4819737"].var`

```
pd.DataFrame({'gene_ids': {'RP11-34P13.3': 'ENSG00000243485',
  'FAM138A': 'ENSG00000237613',
  'OR4F5': 'ENSG00000186092',
  'RP11-34P13.7': 'ENSG00000238009',
  'RP11-34P13.8': 'ENSG00000239945'}})

`anno_GSE159115`
pd.DataFrame({'total_UMI': {'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': 5190,
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': 4953,
  'SI_18854_AAACCTGCACGGCTAC-1': 6434,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTGTTGAGG-1': 7730,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': 5044},
 'no_genes': {'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': 1099,
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': 1389,
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGAGGGAAACA-1': 2160,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTGTTGAGG-1': 2443,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': 1196},
 'pct_MT': {'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': 0.0244701348747592,
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': 0.0393700787401575,
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGAGGGAAACA-1': 0.0248678893378924,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTGTTGAGG-1': 0.0341526520051746,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': 0.0224028548770817},
 'sample': {'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': 'SI_18854',
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': 'SI_18854',
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGAGGGAAACA-1': 'SI_18854',
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTGTTGAGG-1': 'SI_18854',
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': 'SI_18854'},
 'gene_per_1kUMI': {'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': 211.753371868979,
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': 280.436099333737,
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGAGGGAAACA-1': 335.716506061548,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTGTTGAGG-1': 316.041397153946,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': 237.113402061856},
 'no_genes_log10': {'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': 3.04099769242349,
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': 3.14270224573762,
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGAGGGAAACA-1': 3.33445375115093,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTGTTGAGG-1': 3.38792346697344,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': 3.07773117965239},
 'cellfilt': {'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': False,
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': False,
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGAGGGAAACA-1': False,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTGTTGAGG-1': False,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': False},
 'doublet_score': {'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': 0.0345195045682442,
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': 0.0226007163211419,
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGAGGGAAACA-1': 0.0175096260036415,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTGTTGAGG-1': 0.0241521945273824,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': 0.0297453243135695},
 'doublet': {'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': False,
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': False,
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGAGGGAAACA-1': False,
  'SI_18854_AAACCTGCAGTCAGCC': False,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': False},
 'cluster': {'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': 9,
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': 9,
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGAGGGAAACA-1': 11,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTGTTGAGG-1': 11,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': 9},
 'anno': {'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': 'Tcell',
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': 'Tcell',
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGAGGGAAACA-1': 'Tcell_CD8',
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTGTTGAGG-1': 'Tcell_CD8',
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': 'Tcell'},
 'label': {'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': '9:Tcell',
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': '9:Tcell',
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGAGGGAAACA-1': '11:Tcell_CD8',
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTGTTGAGG-1': '11:Tcell_CD8',
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': '9:Tcell'},
 'patient': {'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': 'SS_2005',
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': 'SS_2005',
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGAGGGAAACA-1': 'SS_2005',
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTGTTGAGG-1': 'SS_2005',
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': 'SS_2005'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import anndata

anno_GSE159115 = pd.DataFrame({
    'anno': {
        'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': 'Tcell',
        'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': 'Tcell',
        'SI_18854_AACCGCGAGGGAAACA-1': 'Tcell_CD8',
        'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTGTTGAGG-1': 'Tcell_CD8',
        'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': 'Tcell'
    }
})

# Simulate some AnnData objects and store them in a dictionary.
# The key of the dictionary is the sample_id and the value is the corresponding AnnData object.
dfs_GSE159115 = {
    'sample1': anndata.AnnData(obs=pd.DataFrame(index=['AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1', 'AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1'])),
    'sample2': anndata.AnnData(obs=pd.DataFrame(index=['AAACCTGCACGGCTAC-1', 'AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1']))
}

# Extract the substring after the last underscore from the index
anno_GSE159115['short_index'] = anno_GSE159115.index.str.split('_').str[-1]

# Function to map and add the column
def map_and_add(adata, anno_df):
    # Map the 'anno' column to the AnnData object's index
    mapped_values = adata.obs.index.map(anno_df.set_index('short_index')['anno'])
    # Assign this mapped series to a new column in adata.obs
    adata.obs['anno'] = mapped_values

# Apply the function to each AnnData object in the dictionary
for sample_id, adata in dfs_GSE159115.items():
    map_and_add(adata, anno_GSE159115)


for sample_id, adata in dfs_GSE159115.items():
    print(sample_id)
    print(adata.obs)
```

[image]